# Standard Windows Keyboard - wrong keys recognised

Tags: macos, keyboard, mac-mini

I have a classic British Windows keyboard plugged into my Mac Mini. I'm sure I had it working but now it's not... I can choose between these two layouts but neither is correct:

[image]
[image]

My keyboard, like every other UK PC keyboard, has backslash to the left of Z, and nothing to the right of [ & ].

How can I reset this - reinitialise the keyboard?

Comment: I should say I did originally get the "we don't recognise this keyboard, press the key next to the left shift key" (backslash) and I thought it was working. But that now seems to have been lost, can I force OSX to show the dialog again?

Comment: Your machine thinks your "keyboard type" is ANSI, when it should be recognizing it as ISO.  Hopefully Tetsujin's answer will let you do that.  See also http://m10lmac.blogspot.com/2009/12/fixing-keyboard-type-problems.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Delete the keyboard prefs file at `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.keyboardtype.plist` & reboot.
That should allow you to try again with the setup.

The layout you're looking for [I think] is this one for British PC, which looks correct for my standard UK PC extended keyboard.

[image]

Comment: I don't appear to _have_ that file. I do remember when the dialog came up I was asked to choose if it was ANSI or ISO as Tom mentions. But if it won't let me 'uninstall' the keyboard what can I do?

Comment: Seems I don't have that file either, but I have an Apple keyboard which I understand may not need to generate one. I've pretty much exhausted my not inconsiderable Google-Fu on this & the best I can come up with is to connect a different keyboard, then if the assistant doesn't pop up,try manually running /System/Library/CoreServices/KeyboardSetupAssistant.app That may at least generate the file, giving you 2 options; swap back, or trash the file & swap back... I know.. the solution peters out badly at the end :)

Comment: Ah, it was in /Library not ~/Library. It _seems_ to be working now.

Comment: \o/ Glad you found it. I'll fix my Answer; apologies for the error.

Comment: For some reason the picture of my keyboard layout is still wrong, not like yours, but it is working right. You don't have extra profiles installed or bootcamp do you?

Comment: I have a Bootcamp Win 7 & Parallels Win XP, 7, 8 & 10 - but idk if any of those may have installed additional keyboard layouts, sorry.

Answer (score -1):

Keyboard Layout files worked best for me.
Sorry for the german guide, best use google translate.
https://administrator.de/tutorial/deutsche-pc-tastatur-am-apple-mac-einrichten-221078.html

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your link concerns how to install a custom keyboard layout in MacOS and has really nothing  to do with the problem of a machine mistakenly recognizing whether a hardware keyboard is ISO or ANSI type.  I suggest you delete.